# Qubit fidelity of DWAVE device

Tags: experimental-realization, fidelity, d-wave

Since DWAVE quantum device is constructed using superconducting flux qubits, each qubit cannot be produced identically so that the fidelity of the qubit must be different.  DWAVE only provides the information of their devices in terms of number of qubits, couplers, etc without any calibration data of each qubit on their [website](https://www.dwavesys.com/solutions-and-products/systems/).

I was wondering if we can find some information about the qubit fidelity of DWAVE machine. Since the number of qubits is quite huge, I assume it's time-consuming to calibrate the device and methods like randomized benchmarking are not applicable anymore. Is there any specific calibration method for that?